# ngStyle backgroud image in Angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ngStyle tag to my div element for setting the image, but the image is not working,

i have tried to set the ngStyle background as follows

```
<div  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(${profilePicPrefix + profileService.userDetails.profile_img})'}"  class="profilepic">
</div>
```

and

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ profilePicPrefix + profileService.userDetails.profile_img +')'}"  
// not working - String concatenation
```

and

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(${profilePicPrefix + profileService.userDetails.profile_img})'}"
// not working
```

i am getting blank screen, image is not rendering but build was successful.

Comment: What HTTP response do you get for the request?

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic, i will get the image url

Comment: Have you seen that or you are supposing?

Comment: Instead of applying all string concatenation login inside, create a method in `ts` file which should return the exact string like `url('http://image')` and then you can just use that method in html `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': getImageUrl()}"`

Answer (score 0):

I used something as given, please try it

```
 [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(' + profileService.userDetails.profile_img + ')'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotation marks inside the parenthesis.

Try with this

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url("'+ profilePicPrefix + profileService.userDetails.profile_img +'")'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 [style.background-image]="'url('+ profileService.userDetails.profile_img +')'">
```